# Passing byte pointer to CLR function

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Just for exercise I was trying to allocate a byte buffer on the stack with C# and pass it to `Socket.Send`

```
byte *buffer = stackalloc byte[256];

// fill buffer

socket.Send(buffer, 3 + _body.Length + 1, SocketFlags.None);
```

But Visual Studio spits out this message:

> Error 27  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'byte*' to 'byte[]'

Is there a way to convert the pointer to the array without allocating a new array

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't. Think about it: a generic pointer lacks the metadata attached to every .NET object, so the array could never be properly handled by the garbage collector. Imagine you hand off your "array" to code that then stores it in an instance field -- that code (verified managed code) would fail when you deallocate the memory behind its back (in the case of `stackalloc`, when the containing method ends).

If you want a managed array, you'll have to allocate a managed array, no way around it.

Comment: And if the OP is worried about excessive allocations, he can always maintain a buffer pool.

Comment: @MikeStrobel: yes -- although garbage collection is especially suited to handling this scenario when the allocations are small and short lived. Even so, for sockets in particular, [SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs) was introduced to reduce allocation overhead for very high performance scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

The [stackalloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx) keyword is used in an unsafe code context to allocate a block of memory on the stack.

Your code is pure managed code,  you should use new instead of stackalloc.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

// fill buffer

socket.Send(buffer, 3 + _body.Length + 1, SocketFlags.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the method, if you want to use it to write data to a socket, it is possible:

```
[DllImport("ws2_32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern unsafe int send(IntPtr socketHandle, byte* pinnedBuffer, int len, SocketFlags socketFlags);
//...
send(socket.Handle, buffer, 3 + _body.Length + 1, SocketFlags.None);
```

But this method lacks many control checks and logging etc., so you should really rather use the managed alternative already posted here.